# Android shortcuts - intent doesn't open app

Tags: android

I've two classes:

1) public class **ClassA** extends ClassB

2) public abstract class **ClassB** extends AppCompatActivity...

For both classes, I use code below. ClassA works (I get a logcat, that onCreate was hit), but ClassB does not. It returns "App isn't installed" which made me think, that my targetPackage is wrong, but, ClassA works, so I got confused. Is it because classB is abstract?

```
<shortcut
    android:shortcutId="..."
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="..."
    android:shortcutShortLabel="..."
    android:shortcutLongLabel="..."
    android:shortcutDisabledMessage="...">
    <intent
        android:action="..."
        android:targetPackage="this.is.example.X" // where X is product flavor
        android:targetClass="this.is.example.ClassA" />
    <categories android:name="..." />
</shortcut>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's impossible to create a shortcut to the `abstract` activity class.

Comment: Thank you, didn't know that! Is there an alternative? I have three classes.
ClassChild1(phone), ClassChild2(tablet) and ClassParent. Both ClassChild1 and ClassChild2 extends ClassParent. How to structure shortcuts intents for both phones and tablets?

Comment: @Pete In case of shortcut there's no alternative. Just keep in mind that you can create shortcuts only for public intents are declared in App's manifest.